# Bug in recursive divide et impera binary search

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search, divide-and-conquer

I wrote a divide and conquer binary search, it works in all cases except for when I search for the first or the last number, where instead of giving me 0 and v.size()-1 as the result it gives me 1 and v.size()-2.

For example if I input n=5 and the vector {1; 2; 3; 4; 5} and search for 1 it returns me "1" instead of "0".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int binarySearch(std::vector<int> v, int nr, int left, int right)
{
int mij = (left + right) / 2;

if (v[mij] < nr){
    binarySearch(v, nr, mij+1, right);
}
else if (v[mij] > nr){
    binarySearch(v, nr, left, mij-1);
}
else if (v[mij] == nr){
    return mij;
}
else return -1;
}

int main()
{
vector <int> v;

int n; cout << "n="; cin >>n;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    int x;
    cout << "v[" << i << "]=";
    cin >> x;
    v.push_back(x);
}

cout << binarySearch(v, 1, 0, v.size());

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a great opportunity to practice your debugging skills. Fire up your debugger of choice and step through the program line by line. For each line, check whether the program does the thing you would do if you went through the binary search by hand.

Comment: Yes, I did that. The debugger says mij is 0, just before it returns it, yet my screen prints out 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior because you do not return a value from your function in all cases. Your program might crash, do nothing, format your hard drive or give you the correct value - it's undefined what happens. In this case, your compiler knows exactly what the problem is and really wants to tell you, but you need to ask it: Turn on the warnings (e.g. `-Wall` in gcc or clang).

> `warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`

Currently, you do not return a value if you recurse, which is easily fixed:

```
int binarySearch(std::vector<int> v, int nr, int left, int right)
{
    int mij = (left + right) / 2;

    if (v[mij] < nr){
        return binarySearch(v, nr, mij+1, right);
//      ^^^^^^
    }
    else if (v[mij] > nr){
        return binarySearch(v, nr, left, mij-1);
//      ^^^^^^
    }
    else if (v[mij] == nr){
        return mij;
    }
    else return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your binary search works fine but You sure you had passed inputs to the program correctly? input should be like this -

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
```

output

```
0
```

you can verify that here [link to code](https://code.hackerearth.com/dcef18Y)

Comment: I did it on the computers at school and passed that exact input and stepped through it with a debugger and mij was 0 right before it was returned yet the screen prints out 1. Now I tried it with my PC, same thing but it prints out 6422208

Comment: @Lastrevio2 have gone through the link i posted ?

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to enter the input there.

Comment: above compile and run there's a checkbox labelling with **Use custom input for testing your code** by clicking that your inputs can be given to the program.